# TitledBorder around JTextField

Tags: java, swing

In java, when I use a TitledBorder around a JTextField, part of the JTextField spills over the TitledBorder in all directions. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: A JTextField inside a JPanel with a border inside another JPanel inside a JFrame? panelception

Comment: post a screenshot, for better help.

Comment: And also your GUI setup code.

Comment: No need to. @Legend has your answer -- nest your components.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace the border of the textfield with a `TitledBorder` you lose the natural border of the field. The solution is to create a `CompoundBorder`that combines the `TitledBorder` with the border of the field:

```
JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
field.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Title"), field.getBorder()));
```

However the TitledBorder still inherits the background color of the textfield.

Another solution is to embed the textfield in a `JPanel` and put the `TitledBorder` on the panel:

```
JTextField field = new JTextField(10);

JPanel borderPanel = new JPanel();
borderPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Title"));
borderPanel.add(field);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class AA
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FrameCreator Frame= new FrameCreator();
        Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class FrameCreator extends JFrame
{
    public FrameCreator()
    {
        int height=100;
        int width=300;
        setSize(width,height);
        setLocation(0,0);

        setTitle("TextField example");

        showPanel=new JPanel();
        textFieldPanel=new JPanel();

        label=new JLabel("Sentence");
        label.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,12));

        showPanel.add(label);
        add(showPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        textfield=new JTextField("Sentence", 20);
        textfield.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Name"));
        textfield.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento1)
                {

                    String sentence=textfield.getText();


                    label.setText(sentence);
                }
            });


        textFieldPanel.add(textfield);
        add(textFieldPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    JLabel label;
    JPanel showPanel, textFieldPanel;
    String sentence;
    JTextField textfield;
}
```

I have used textfield.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Name"));

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up writing my own border. It's less flexible than the JDK's `TitledBorder`, but at least it respect the border

[image: combobox with border]

```kotlin
class ComboBoxTitleBorder(private val originalBorder: Border, private val title: String) : AbstractBorder() {
    private val TEXT_MARGIN_LEFT = 15
    private val TEXT_SPACING = 2
    private val TEXT_TOP_ALIGNMENT = 2
    private val label = JLabel().apply {
        isOpaque = false
        putClientProperty(BasicHTML.propertyKey, null)
    }

    override fun paintBorder(c: Component?, g: Graphics, x: Int, y: Int, width: Int, height: Int) {
        if (c == null) return
        val insets = getBorderInsets(originalBorder, c, JBUI.emptyInsets())
        val edge = 0
        val label = getLabel(c)
        val size = label.getPreferredSize()

        val borderX: Int = x + edge
        val borderY: Int = y + edge
        val borderW: Int = width - edge - edge
        val borderH: Int = height - edge - edge


        val labelX = x + TEXT_MARGIN_LEFT
        val labelY = y - TEXT_TOP_ALIGNMENT
        val labelH = size.height

        var labelW = width - insets.left - insets.right
        if (labelW > size.width) {
            labelW = size.width
        }

        val g2 = g.create()
        if (g2 is Graphics2D) {
            val path: Path2D = Path2D.Float()
            path.append(Rectangle(borderX, borderY, borderW, labelY - borderY), false)
            path.append(Rectangle(borderX, labelY, labelX - borderX - TEXT_SPACING, labelH), false)
            path.append(
                Rectangle(
                    labelX + labelW + TEXT_SPACING,
                    y,
                    borderX - labelX + borderW - labelW - TEXT_SPACING,
                    labelH
                ), false)
            path.append(Rectangle(borderX, labelY + labelH, borderW, borderY - labelY + borderH - labelH), false)
            g2.clip(path)
        }
        originalBorder.paintBorder(c, g2, borderX, borderY, borderW, borderH)
        g2.dispose()

        g.translate(labelX, labelY)
        label.setSize(labelW, labelH)
        label.paint(g)
        g.translate(-labelX, -labelY)
    }

    override fun getBorderInsets(c: Component): Insets {
        return originalBorder.getBorderInsets(c);
    }

    private fun getLabel(c: Component): JLabel {
        label.setText(title)
        label.setFont(...Your font)
        label.setForeground(...You color)
        label.setComponentOrientation(c.componentOrientation)
        label.setEnabled(c.isEnabled)
        return label
    }

    private fun getBorderInsets(border: Border, c: Component?, insets: Insets): Insets {
        return when (border) {
            is AbstractBorder -> border.getBorderInsets(c, insets)
            else -> border.getBorderInsets(c).let {
                insets.apply { set(it.top, it.left, it.bottom, it.right) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```